# Windows Forms ComboBox - case insensitive data-binding

Tags: c#, winforms

If I'm databinding a winforms combo box, is there a way to make the binding case insensitive?

For example if the combo box is bound to a property whose value is FOO, get it to select combo box item with value of Foo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible. This is internally implemented using reflection which is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the game, but here's what I've done to allow case insensitive binding to a WinForms ComboBox:

I've created my own class that inherits from ComboBox, and have added the following property to bind my data to (pardon the auto-conversion from VB.NET):

```
public object Value {
    get {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ValueMember)) {
            return Text;
        } else {
            return SelectedValue;
        }
    }
    set {
        if (DesignMode)
            return;

        // If we're databound, Value is the SelectedValue.  Otherwise, it's the Text.
        object oldValue = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ValueMember) ? Text : SelectedValue;

        // Want to make sure we're comparing apples to apples, and not specific instances of apples.
        string strOld = oldValue == null ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(oldValue);
        string strNew = value == null ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(value);

        if (!string.Equals(strOld, strNew, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            if (ValueMember.HasValue) {
                if (value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(value))) {
                    SelectedItem = Items.OfType<object>.FirstOrDefault((System.Object i) => string.Equals(Convert.ToString(FilterItemOnProperty(i, ValueMember)), strNew, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                } else {
                    SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
            } else {
                Text = value != null ? value.ToString : string.Empty;
            }
            ValidateField();
            if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ValidateField` is a custom method that you can probably ignore, but you'll want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the Value property.

Comment: Note that the data type that you'd bind to the Value property in the above code should be a basic value type (or String) and not a complex object, or else the Convert.ToString could return the same string for two different objects (a string representing the object's Type, if the object's class doesn't override the .ToString method).  Since you're likely using this to bind a field in a database row to a property or field in the ComboBox's DataSource collection/table, this shouldn't be a problem.